# Validation on blank date field not working

Tags: formula, opportunity, validation

If the opportunity is marked as Closed Won and the opportunity information picklist is set to "Existing Customer Renewal" then the renewal date field cannot be blank.

```
AND (
    ISBlank(Renewal_Date__c), 
    ISPICKVAL(Type, "Existing Customer - Renewal"), 
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won")
)
```

Comment: Hello Tom,have you confirmed that the Validation Rule is active? And that the fields Type/StageName really have those values? I tested your VR on a test sandbox and it worked as expected.

Comment: Hi, I have double checked and it is active. By testing, I selected Existing Customer - Renewal and then Closed Won, without putting a date in and I was able to close the opportunity

Comment: Just tried it, and ISBLANK (datefield) works fine for me. What happens, if you just try with only the ISBLANK condition?

Comment: Sorry about this, I just checked the field within Object Manager and noticed that someone edited the text lable for Type, which retained the original API value. I updated the validation rule and it worked!