# Date field cannot be blank

Tags: validation-rule, datetime

i've got a validation rule on the case object to check 2 fields that cannot be blank.  One of them is a date field.

```
AND(
CONTAINS(RecordType.Name,'Court'),
ISPICKVAL( Status,'Matching' ),
ISBLANK( Ground_Rules_Hearing_Date_Time__c ),
ISBLANK( Court_Location__r.Region__c )
)
```

for the life of me, the rule will not look at the date field.
the other conditions are working.

Troubleshooting already done:

1. Changed ISBLANK to ISNULL on the date field
2. Inserted the field name rather than typing
3. Switched the conditions in case there was an order
4. Removed the date field and the other conditions work
5. Just has the date field and the CONTAINS condition and this does not work

Can anyone see what could be wrong here please?
thankyou in advance
i know it is just simple but it's driving me nuts...LOL!!

Comment: I've looked at this question raised previously and it's seems fairly straight forward, similar to mine

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303111/validation-on-blank-date-field-not-working

Comment: does the date field have a default value defined for it?